# How to find an element by Xpath that contains a text in a list

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium on python.
My case is to search for an element where its xpath contains one of the texts in a list:

```
string_list =[text1, text2, text3, ..]
# this is the straightforward solution but it does not work.
# convert text in the component to lower as the list contains lower case string.
 predicates = [f"contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '{text}')" for text in string_list]
 xpath = "//*[" + " or ".join(predicates) + "]"
 popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
```